# How can I check duplicate record in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Does any one know how can I write a SQL Server script to check whether table is contain duplicate phone number?

Example:

I have a table called customer with following data

```
name   telephone
alvin  0396521254
alan   0396521425
amy    0396521425
```

How can I write a script in SQL Server that can return those records with duplicate telephone number??

Comment: duplicate question marked as duplicate, lol!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To see values with duplicates:

```
  SELECT c.telephone
    FROM CUSTOMER c
GROUP BY c.telephone
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

To see related records in the table for those duplicates:

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM CUSTOMER c
  JOIN (SELECT c.telephone
          FROM CUSTOMER c
      GROUP BY c.telephone
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) x ON x.telephone = c.telephone
```

Comment: @astander: I'd be better if this migraine would go away.  I need to participate more, if I'm to maintain my lead.

Comment: You have a huge enoug buffer as it is. I think you need to take some time off X-)

Comment: @astander: I'm afraid you're within my 30K buffer - you need to cease & desist so equilibrium can be re-established. :p

Comment: What is the difference between both queries?

Comment: The first query will identify the phone numbers that are duplicates, whereas the second will let you have access to all the columns of all the duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
;WITH Duplicates AS (
        SELECT  Telephone
        FROM    Table
        HAVING  COUNT(1) > 1
)
SELECT  t.*
FROm    Table t INNER JOIN
        Duplicates d ON t.Telephone = d.Telephone
```

Or even something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table t
WHERE   EXISTS  (
                    SELECT  1
                    FROM    Table tI    
                    WHERE   tI.Telephone = t.Telephone
                    AND     tI.Name != t.Name
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone will come up with a better solution, but I'll give my crude way anyway.

If it were me I'd use the aggregate COUNT function along with the GROUP BY clause.

I would write an SQL statement such as:

```
SELECT telephone, COUNT(telephone)[Entries] FROM table1
GROUP BY telephone
HAVING Entries > 1
```

That should return any duplicate phone numbers with a count for how many duplicates exist.

Comment: Say what?? which database are you using that allows WHERE clause after GROUP BY, other than HAVING?

Comment: SQL Server allows WHERE when using GROUP BY. Although it would occur prior to the result set so it would most likely need to be HAVING in this case (after the result set is generated the HAVING will be applied). 

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx